# How do I list the count of occurrences using the over() function, but only display the occurrences that are listed in the result 3 or more times?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I list the amount of times each account number has occurred if I only want to see the ones that have occurred 3 times or more?

I'm using a window OVER() function to get the number of times the account number is listed.

```
SELECT a.ACCOUNTNUMBER AS [Account Number]
    , CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST) AS [Member Name]
    , l.id AS [Loan ID]
    , COUNT(a.ACCOUNTNUMBER)
        OVER(partition by a.ACCOUNTNUMBER) as [Number of 
Tracking Record] 
    , n.EMAIL AS [Email]
    , n.HOMEPHONE AS [Phone Number]
FROM dbo.account a
INNER JOIN dbo.LOAN l
ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = l.PARENTACCOUNT
INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
AND l.ID = lt.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.NAME n 
ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = n.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE lt.type = 46
AND l.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
AND lt.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
AND a.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
AND lt.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
GROUP BY a.ACCOUNTNUMBER, n.FIRST, n.MIDDLE, n.LAST, l.id, n.email, 
n.HOMEPHONE
ORDER BY [Account Number]
```

Right now my result is giving me the number of times all of the accounts are listed in the "Number of Tracking Record" column. I want to see only the account numbers that have "3" occurrences or above.

My current result:

[image: My current result]

My Desired Result:

[image: My Desired Result]

Comment: Use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: select * (or relevant list of columns) from (select a.ACCOUNTNUMBER..... i.e. your existing query) where [Number of Tracking Record] >= 3 ORDER BY [Account Number]
Move the ORDER BY column to outside the subquery, don't just duplicate it :)

Comment: @seventyeightist, I get this error: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *   -- edit to include only your relevant columnns
FROM
(
SELECT a.ACCOUNTNUMBER AS [Account Number]
    , CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST) AS [Member Name]
    , l.id AS [Loan ID]
    , COUNT(a.ACCOUNTNUMBER)
        OVER(partition by a.ACCOUNTNUMBER) as [Number of 
Tracking Record] 
    , n.EMAIL AS [Email]
    , n.HOMEPHONE AS [Phone Number]
FROM dbo.account a
INNER JOIN dbo.LOAN l
ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = l.PARENTACCOUNT
INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
AND l.ID = lt.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.NAME n 
ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = n.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE lt.type = 46
AND l.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
AND lt.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
AND a.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
AND lt.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
GROUP BY a.ACCOUNTNUMBER, n.FIRST, n.MIDDLE, n.LAST, l.id, n.email, 
n.HOMEPHONE
) MyQuery
WHERE MyQuery.[Number of Tracking Record] >= 3
ORDER BY [Account Number]
```

I added an "outer" query around yours, using yours as a subquery, and filtered it for those with just the >=3 condition. And I moved the ORDER BY from your inside query to the outer query, as it's just used for ordering the results and not used in the computation itself.

Comment: Sorry, it works. However, I now need just one row listed for each account number. Since some of the accounts have different emails and phone numbers, I'm getting multiple results for the same account.
Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: So you have multiple records for an account number, potentially (but not necessarily) with different email addresses, phone numbers associated with them? If there is more than one set of personal info for the same account number, how do you choose which one you want to display in the final result? Or does it not matter and you just want the account numbers without any personal info associated?

Comment: Yes, there can be one account number with multiple names, emails and phone numbers. I tried using 
SELECT MyQuery.[Account Number]
  , MAX(MyQuery.[Member Name]) AS [Member Name]
  , MyQuery.[Loan ID]
  , MyQuery.[Number of Tracking Record]
  , MyQuery.Email
  , MyQuery.[Phone Number])
But it doesn't seem to be working.
I just want one of the records, it doesn't matter which one.

Comment: @lexirainbow if you "just want one of the records, it doesn't matter which one" do you need to see the personal info in the results of that query at all? If not, and you just want the account number ... remove those fields (phone number etc) from the inner query and the group by.

Would a set of results with "Account Number - Number of Tracking Record" (without any name etc) satisfy your requirement? (and I can edit the answer accordingly)